# USB Bluetooth data

Tags: bluetooth

I am curious what the datapath for a bluetooth audio dongle is on the Pi. I need to know this so that I can intercept the data. What I would like is to connect Bluetooth and grab any audio for processing.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! This site is not a discussion forum -- please take the tour again and pay attention to the Get answers to practical, detailed questions part. I am putting this on hold as I think it is too broad right now and just inviting for endless discussions. Please be more specific. You can always edit your question and call for a re-open.

Comment: Fair, all editing has been done.